# Getting HTML instead of JSON response and 500 status code when sending header Content-Type as application/json

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, web-crawler

I've been trying to get data from https://etherscan.io/nft-transfers?a=0x90f37809cccf13705a1f5e9fca645ba3fd58773c.

To get 100 rows it sends a AJAX request to https://etherscan.io/nft-transfers.aspx/GetTableData_NftTransfers and gets a JSON response.

When I send the request from Python script with same payload and headers except the Content-Type it gives me a HTML response with only 25 rows as data but when I include Content-Type header it is giving me a 500 status code.

I unable to understand what is the issue here.

I am using Python and httpx framework.

```
nft_transactions = "https://etherscan.io/nft-transfers?a=0x90f37809cccf13705a1f5e9fca645ba3fd58773c"
nft_transaction_post_url = "https://etherscan.io/nft-transfers.aspx/GetTableData_NftTransfers"

with Client(http2=True) as client:
    resp = client.get(nft_transactions, headers=HEADERS, timeout=30)
    print(resp.status_code)
    HEADERS["Referer"] = "https://etherscan.io/nft-transfers?a=0x90f37809cccf13705a1f5e9fca645ba3fd58773c"
    HEADERS["Accept"] = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
    HEADERS["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    HEADERS["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
    HEADERS["Cookie"] = "ASP.NET_SessionId=pluwldlu2g1prywcul3xm54k; bitmedia_fid=eyJmaWQiOiIzMzVkMWI3MTFhZmQ2NDQ2YzZkY2U5Y2ViYjRmMjJjOSIsImZpZG5vdWEiOiJhYjliNmRiYjk2Y2Q2ZmZmMzBlNjAwMWM0NDFmOTMxNyJ9; etherscan_cookieconsent=True; displaymode=light; _gid=GA1.2.1296145474.1687081165; etherscan_switch_age_datetime=Age; _ga_T1JC9RNQXV=deleted; __cflb=02DiuFnsSsHWYH8WqVXbZzkeTrZ6gtmGUCT1KWiuzFuy6; cf_clearance=uv8ynqXUbgnHxXnMjQv_V_oWrdyogkfcQTbXWmtsq2M-1687510221-0-150; _gat_gtag_UA_46998878_6=1; __cf_bm=yRJObmuJxZnXbIzZCgX.BmSUQ_xLstUEHCrheJZ5CGg-1687529771-0-Af9WCdcIeQIKrGBpEBsw5WlJ875g9lbHKD93cEdNntyt8KfJBqlWQTD4V8WjmUsN5A==; _ga_T1JC9RNQXV=GS1.1.1687529769.78.1.1687529785.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.1028829820.1685819037"
    HEADERS["Sec-Fetch-Mode"] = "cors"
    HEADERS["Sec-Fetch-Dest"] = "empty"
    del HEADERS["Sec-Fetch-User"]
    resp = client.post(nft_transaction_post_url, data=payload, headers=HEADERS)
    print(resp.status_code)
```

Headers and payload

```
HEADERS = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,"
              "application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua": '"Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"',
    "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "Windows",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
    "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 "
                  "Safari/537.36",
    "Origin": "https://etherscan.io"
}

payload = {
  "dataTableModel": {
    "draw": 2,
    "columns": [
      {
        "data": "preview",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": True,
        "orderable": False,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": False
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "txhash",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": True,
        "orderable": False,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": False
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "txMethod",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": True,
        "orderable": False,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": False
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "dt",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": True,
        "orderable": False,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": False
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "_from",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": True,
        "orderable": False,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": False
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "arrow",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": True,
        "orderable": False,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": False
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "_to",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": True,
        "orderable": False,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": False
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "type",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": True,
        "orderable": False,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": False
        }
      },
      {
        "data": "tokenAddress",
        "name": "",
        "searchable": True,
        "orderable": False,
        "search": {
          "value": "",
          "regex": False
        }
      }
    ],
    "order": [

    ],
    "start": 0,
    "length": 100,
    "search": {
      "value": "",
      "regex": False
    },
    "Ext": "0x90f37809cccf13705a1f5e9fca645ba3fd58773c"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try passing `Content-Length` header, with value equal to total length of payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was doing wrong. I had to pass the json data through the ***json*** parameter and if sending it through the ***data*** parameter I need to use ***json.dumps(payload)*** to make it work.

```
resp = client.post(nft_transaction_post_url, json=payload, headers=HEADERS)
# OR 
resp = client.post(nft_transaction_post_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=HEADERS)
```

Without that its sending the data as form data and that is why the server is unable to understand my request.